# How to hide the view of last clicked item on the recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

ViewHolder:

```
class HomeViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val songName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtNameSong)
    val songArtist: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtNameArtist)
    val cardContent: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardContent)
    val pauseButton: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.pauseButton)
}
```

Adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val text = songInfoList[position]
    holder.songName.text = text[0]
    holder.songArtist.text = text[1]
    val path = text[2]
    holder.cardContent.setOnClickListener {
        playMusic(path)
        holder.pauseButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    holder.pauseButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            holder.pauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play)
            mediaPlayer.pause()
         } else {
            holder.pauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)
            mediaPlayer.start()
         }
    }
}
```

The `pauseButton` appears whenever the user clicks the item on the recyclerView, and the music is played.
I want to disappear `pauseButton` for the previous clicked when the user clicks on the new item and `pauseButton` appear for the new entry. But, I'm unable to do this. Tell me how to do this.
Whenever I click on the new content on the recyclerView the `pauseButton` should appear for the latest item and disappear for the previous item.

Comment: Create field `var previous: View` and when you click item do `previous = item`. After next click hide pause button for `previous` and again do `previous = item` (current item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current function is working for only one item of the recyclerview, so you can't do it here.
If you want to do it, you can do like this.
You can add `isPlay` value to SongInfoModel and when the play clicked you can set `isPlay = false` for all songs except current playing song.

so the code will be like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val text = songInfoList[position]
    holder.songName.text = text[0]
    holder.songArtist.text = text[1]
    val path = text[2]

    holder.cardContent.setOnClickListener {
        playMusic(path)
        holder.pauseButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    if(songInfoList[position].getIsPlaying){
       holder.pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }else{
       holder.pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    }

    holder.pauseButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            holder.pauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play)
            mediaPlayer.pause()
         } else {
            holder.pauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)
            mediaPlayer.start()
         }

         setPlayingSong(position)
    }

}


    public void setPlayingSong(int pos){
       for (int i = 0; i < songInfoList.size; i++){
         songInfoList.get(i).setIsPlaying(false);
        }
       songInfoList.get(pos).setIsPlaying(true);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But also, the image of pauseButton isn't changing when I click on it. And the button for last clicked disappear only when the new button is clicked twice.

Comment: It worked correctly when I put setPlayingSong(position) inside the cardContent listener, instead of pauseButton listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold state in your RecyclerView.Adapter

Inside Adapter:

```
private var playingPosition: Int? = null
```

when a click event happens:

```
//Update previously position
playingPosition?.let {
    models.get(playingPosition).playingState = false
    notifyItemChanged(playingPosition)
}
//update new position
models.get(position).playingState = true
playingPosition = position
notifyItemChanged(position)
```

Also, your model should hold the playing state:`

```
data class Model(...: Int, ...: String, ..., playingState: Boolean)
```

Inside onBindViewHolder:

```
if (model.playingState) view.visibility = View.VISIBLE else view.visibility = VIEW.GONE
```

Comment: I'm not using model for this one.

Comment: @AKSHAYKUMAR Your RecyclerView needs data and it is represented as a model it Could be a `List<String>` so you need to change to `data class model(...: String, playingState: Boolean)` and `List<Model>`

Comment: I'm using ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>() for storing the data of the song(name, artist_name , path). I'm using--            val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST
        )
        val c: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ).....for getting the songs details from device. How to add model in this?

Comment: @AKSHAYKUMAR so ArrayList<ArrayList<Model>> I belive.

Comment: So I need to add data class SongModel(). And in this model, I need to add these three details?

Comment: @AKSHAYKUMAR Yes, All I've added to your data is `PlayingState` the rest of data in that model is up to you as you want to show them to the user.